# Why is my variable returning undefined?

Tags: jquery

I'm in the process of learning jQuery and I'm wondering why my **stylesheet** variable is returning undefined.

```
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>jQuery Events</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="day.css">  
</head>
<body>

<h1>My Website</h1>


<button data-file="day">Day</button>
<button data-file="night">Night</button>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>


(function() {

    var link = $('link');

    $('button').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $('this'),
            stylesheet = $this.data('file');

        console.log(stylesheet);

        link.attr('href', stylesheet + '.css');

    });

})();


</script>
```

All of my CSS and files are perfectly in check. And I can't seem to spot any general errors in code punctuation. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: You don't have an element with tag name `this` (i.e. `<this />`). Hence the collection return by `$('this')` is empty. I guess you meant to pass the element the handler is bound to, i.e. `$(this)`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing `$('this')`, write `$(this)`.